# How to find the sum of a series of repeated numbers?

Tags: javascript

The question I'm trying to solve is:

- Find the sum of the series (3 + 33 + 333 + 3333 + ... + n), to n terms, where n is an input provided by the user (using prompt).
- Example: Given 5. So the series will become (3 + 33 + 333 + 3333 + 33333).
  Expected output: 37035

This is my code:

```
const number = 5;
let sum = 3;
let add;

for (i = 0; i <= number; i++){
  add = "";
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    add += 3;
    sum = add * 10 + 3
  }
  sum = sum  + *5;
}
console.log(sum);
```

It's not giving me the desired outcome (which is obviously the issue I'm running into). I haven't used prompt yet because I don't know how to implement it. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for all your responses and solutions. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop. Use just a single loop, and inside, increment `add` based on the power of 10 of the current iteration, and add the result to the sum:

```js
const count = 3
let sum = 0;

let add = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
  add += 3 * 10 ** i;
  sum += add;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `padEnd()` method to add padding at end of a string. Please check the snippet for the solution by using the `padEnd()` method. In this way, you can avoid string concatenation or extra loop.

[Please check the link to know more about the method padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

```js
const count = 5;
let number = 3;
let sum = 0;

for(i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
  sum += Number(number.toString().padEnd(i, number.toString()));

  console.log(i.toString() + ". " + number.toString().padEnd(i, number.toString()));
}

console.log("Sum: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you ask i think, so i turn to string the iteration number in order to add it to an array and then reduce javascript property to sum all it's elements!!

```js
const number = 5;
let sum = 3;
let added = '';
let add = [];
sum = sum.toString();
added = sum;
for(let i = 0; i<number; i++){
  add.push(added);
  added += sum;
}
let result = add.reduce((ant,sum)=>{
  return parseInt(ant) + parseInt(sum);
});
console.log(result);
```

Edit: for the prompt question here's [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) that i hope it helps you!

You can use it this way: const number = prompt("enter how much numbers");

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```js
  const sumNum = 3;
  const number = Number(prompt('Please enter a number for repeatitions: '));
  let sum = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      sum += sumNum;
    }
    if (i < number) sum += '+';
  }
  let total = 0;
  sum = sum.split('+');
  sum.pop(); //to remove last empty field

  while (sum.length) {
    total += Number.parseFloat(sum.shift());
  }
  console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

To repeat a number:

```
const x = 3;
Number(`${x}`.repeat(1)); //=> 3
Number(`${x}`.repeat(2)); //=> 33
Number(`${x}`.repeat(3)); //=> 333
Number(`${x}`.repeat(4)); //=> 3333
Number(`${x}`.repeat(5)); //=> 33333
```

So from such array `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]` we can do:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3].map((x, i) => Number(`${x}`.repeat(i+1)));
//=> [3, 33, 333, 3333, 33333]
```

But we don't need to manually fill an array with *n* identical numbers:

```
const n = 5;
const x = 3;
Array(n).fill(x);
//=> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Or:

```
Array.from(Array(n), () => x);
//=> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

But obviously if we can apply a function on each item we may as well produce the full series:

```
Array.from(Array(n), (_, i) => Number(`${x}`.repeat(i+1)));
//=> [3, 33, 333, 3333, 33333]
```

Finally we can reduce the series to the sum of all numbers:

```
[3, 33, 333, 3333, 33333].reduce((tot, x) => tot + x, 0);
//=> 37035
```

So altogether we have:

```
const n = 5; // use prompt() but don't forget to coerce the result into a number
const x = 3;

Array.from(Array(n), (_, i) => Number(`${x}`.repeat(i+1)))
  .reduce((tot, x) => tot + x, 0);
```

If you don't need to produce a series then a recursive function is perhaps simpler:

```
const sum_series =
  (x, n, tot=0) =>
    n === 0
      ? tot
      : sum_series(x, n-1, tot+=Number(`${x}`.repeat(n)))

sum_series(3, 5);
//=> 37035
```